# cudaMemcpy doesn't work

Tags: c++, cuda

In the following code there's the cudaMemcpy not working, it returns an error, and the program exits. What can be the problem? It doesn't seem to me I'm doing something illegal, and the size of the vectors seem fine to me.

It might be possible the algorithm does something wrong at some point but the idea is correct I guess. The code is to sum n numbers by doing some partial sums in parallel, and then re-iterate.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

__device__ int aug_vec(int *vec, const int& i, const int& size) {
    return (i >= size) ? 0 : vec[i];
}

__global__ void sumVectorElements(int *vec,const int& size) {
    const int i = (blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x);
    vec[i] = aug_vec(vec, 2*i, size) + aug_vec(vec, 2 * i + 1, size);
}

__host__ int parallel_sum(int *vec,const int& size) {

    cudaError_t err;
    int *d_vec, *cp_vec;
    int n_threads = (size >> 1) + (size & 1);

    cp_vec = new int[size];
    err = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_vec, size * sizeof(int));

    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        std::cout << "error in cudaMalloc!" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    err = cudaMemcpy(d_vec, vec, size*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        std::cout << "error in cudaMemcpy!" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int curr_size = size;
    while (curr_size > 1) {
        std::cout << "size = " << curr_size << std::endl;
        sumVectorElements<<<1,n_threads>>>(d_vec, curr_size);
        curr_size = (curr_size >> 1) + (curr_size & 1);
    }

    err = cudaMemcpy(cp_vec, d_vec, size*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); //THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM!

    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        std::cout << "error in cudaMemcpy" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    err = cudaFree(d_vec);

    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        std::cout << "error in cudaFree" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int rval = cp_vec[0];

    delete[] cp_vec;

    return rval;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const int n_blocks = 1;
    const int n_threads_per_block = 12;

    int vec[12] = { 0 };
    for (auto i = 0; i < n_threads_per_block; ++i) vec[i] = i + 1;
    int sum = parallel_sum(vec, n_threads_per_block);
    std::cout << "Sum = " << sum << std::endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: unless you are using managed memory (which you are not), cuda kernels are not allowed to use reference parameters `const int& size`.  There's no particular need for it there, just change that to `const int size`

Comment: what do you mean with "managed memory"? is it stated somewhere I can't use reference parameters?

Comment: managed memory is defined [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-unified-memory-programming-hd).  It's not stated anywhere that you cannot use reference parameters because it is legal in the UM/managed memory case.   However, the reference parameter effectively expects to take the address of a variable.  This is so that changes to the referenced variable in the called function will show up in calling space.  This is essentially a definition of C++ pass-by-reference.

Comment: The process of taking the reference of (i.e. the address of) a variable means that you are passing a host reference (address) to a device function, and effectively attempting to use that host address in device code.  And that is illegal in CUDA.  (It is also legal to use a reference parameter for data that is pinned and mapped.)

Comment: That was subtle...thank you, it works now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was my algorithm a good design for adding n numbers? In theory is a log n algorithm, but maybe there's better for that.

Comment: The concept is fine.  The implementation is inefficient.  google "cuda parallel reduction" and start reading.  Or there are many questions about it here on the CUDA tag.

Comment: What specific point causes inefficiency?

Comment: There are several points of inefficiency on a GPU.  First of all the algorithm inherently has the opportunity for data re-use.  You are not taking advantage of that.  Another is that your particular data load pattern is not optimal/coalesced.  I'm not going to try and give a complete tutorial on fast parallel reductions on a GPU.  The suggestion I already gave will give you good info.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'm already reading through some stuff.

Comment: Your algorithm also has a logical defect if you extend to a threadblock size larger than a single warp (32 threads).  This won't be easy to spot, but your algorithm does not take into account that warps can execute in any order, as can threadblocks (if you ever extended this to more than 1 block).  Eventually this will result in your code failing to work correctly.  Your algorithm (and all parallel reductions that I know of) require sychronization of some sort.  The only sync you have is the kernel call, and that will not sort out the inter-warp hazard (race condition).

Comment: I'll correct the code ed eventually post in the code review section.

Comment: as a simple test case, extend your code to 512 threads per block, use a thread initialization of 1 instead of `1+i` and run the code with `cuda-memcheck` (which perturbs warp execution order).  When I do that, I get the incorrect result of 288 instead of 512.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cudaMemcpy` operation after the kernel is actually asynchronously reporting an error that is due to the kernel execution.  Your error reporting is primitive.  If you have an error code, you may get more useful information by printing out the result of passing that error code to `cudaGetErrorString()`.

The error is occurring in the kernel due to use of the reference argument:

```
__global__ void sumVectorElements(int *vec,const int& size) {
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any argument you pass to a kernel and expect to be usable in kernel code must refer to data that is passed by value, or else data that is accessible/referenceable from device code.  For example, passing a host pointer to device code is generally not legal in CUDA, because an attempt to dereference a host pointer in device code will fail.

The exceptions to the above would be data/pointers/references that are accessible in device code.  [Unified memory](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-unified-memory-programming-hd) and [pinned/mapped data](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge8d5c17670f16ac4fc8fcb4181cb490c) are two examples, neither of which are being used here.

As a result, the reference parameter involves a reference (an address, basically) for a an item (`size`) in host memory.  When the kernel code attempts to use this item, it must first de-reference it.  The dereferenceing of a host item in device code is illegal in CUDA (unless using UM or pinned memory).

The solution in this case is simple: convert to an ordinary pass-by-value situation:

```
__global__ void sumVectorElements(int *vec,const int size) ...
                                                    ^
                                                 remove ampersand
```